# Varnish ESI for lots of small bits of information

Tags: varnish, edge-side-includes

I've got a standard blog-type application with posts and users that can add those posts to their favorites.

**Goals**

1. When a user looks at a list of posts, they should see an indication (an image) of whether 
   each post is a favorite. Anonymous users don't have any favorites.
2. The list of posts needs to be cached in Varnish (for both anonymous and logged-in users) because it's expensive to calculate.

**Ideas**

Cache the list page in Varnish and use ESI to fetch the favorites information...

1. ... for each post for the user making the current request. **Downside**: 50 ESI requests per page (basically the [N+1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem)).
2. ... as a JSON object which is then stored on the page. On the client, this object is read and the DOM is manipulated to indicate favorites information. **Downside**: doesn't work for users without Javascript.
3. ... as a CSS snippet which is stored in the page. The CSS determines what to display for each post. **Downside**: only works for stylable content (ie, images). Not possible to display text information.

Am I missing any possibilities to accomplish what I want? Idea 3 seems to be the cleverest answer, but it wouldn't work if I also wanted to display the date the user favorited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 2 makes a lot of sense. It makes pages nicely cacheable, and only sacrifices the 'favorite functionality' for people without javascript in their browser.

Who are those people anyway? Still surfing with lynx? ;). And would they accept cookies to make your login mechanism (required for personal favorites) work in the first place, or even login at all?